# Does it matter where you send the body during 'The Heist'?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

During The Heist,

> your companion Jackie

is mortally wounded and dies shortly after escaping the tower. Your taxi advises that transportation of bodies is part of the package chosen and asks you where you would like the body taken.

[image: Options available in game]

I know that if you choose to send the body to Vik, you end up with a phone call later where his mom mentions not receiving the body but gives you some of his things (including his bike).

Does the choice of where to get the body delivered to change anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you send Jackie to his family, it opens up the side quest Heroes, in which you get to attend and speak at his funeral, after spending some time in his garage reminiscing. It's probably the game's storytelling high point to me, so I wouldn't miss it given the choice.

Comment: This option also allows you to get Jackies pistols for your gun wall in the apartment.

Comment: If you send his body to Vik, Arasaka takes the body and zaps it with soulkiller and you have the opportunity to erm... interact with him later, depending on your choices...